# How do I retrieve a value from np.arange?

Tags: arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have the line

```
a = np.arange(2.8,4,0.0001)
```

and later on I need to use it in a for loop as part of a function

```
x(v,n+1) = a(v)*x(v,n)*(1-x(v,n))
```

where v and n are all index numbers for the for loop. But it says that numpy.ndarray object is not callable. Any solutions to this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use brackets in order to properly index an array instead of parenthesis which are used to call a function as you did for np.arange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `a` variable is a numpy.ndarray object and not a function, yet you are accessing `a` as a function. Try the correct syntax for accessing an array:

`a[v]`

instead of:

`a(v)`